# In Radiant Historia, is money a problem?

Tags: radiant-historia

I'm starting a game of Radiant Historia, and as with most RPGs I'm under the pressure of making a choice as to whether I should spend freely or save it all up for a rainy day. Do I have to be wise in spending in this game or do I spend on weapons, armor, etc freely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always fight random battles to make more money, so essentially no, money isn't an issue.

If you fight all the enemies you come across during the normal course of the game (without running past them, or away from them), you'll have enough money already that you won't have to farm.

You can still farm though, and it's not difficult.

Comment: In my experience money isn't the issue in the game, but making sure you are leveled up enough to meet the challenges presented to you.

Comment: I agree. I started skipping battles and the ease with which I handled those that I _had_ to fight started to go down, until I hit a wall with Viola. Also, scrolls and pacts.

Answer (score -1):

You will probably have to grind at some point, but getting levels from grinding is more important than getting money to buy new equipment.  I just buy equipment whenever I have enough money.